# How to connect a Java application to Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am working on a Java application and I have a requirement to connect my application to an Elasticsearch Server.

I am new to both Java and Elasticsearch, and am unsure how to proceed. I couldn't find any documentation that made sense.

Can anybody please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is itself written in Java, and has a [Java Native Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

It also has a REST API that allows any language to interact with it (which is more commonly used, and how I connect to it from Java and Python). You will need to use something like the [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) to make the REST calls.

There is another project, [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest), that adds a more Java OO layer on top of the REST calls.